# afx[...].h missing in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I installed the dreamspark provided VS2013 Professional years ago I hadn't thought I would use c++ so I think I unchecked some things about c++ that I actually don't remember.

*I don't have VS2013 Installer right now*

Now, I've got a MFC application and when I try to compile it, throws an error saying afxwin.h No such file. And when I search in the files there isn't any file with that name.

I searched in SO and I found only posts saying you can't compile if you use VS Express but that's not my case. What should I do or download?

Anyone can help I'd be thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the VS2013 tools.